# SQL Need Date of first service

Tags: sql, join, group-by, db2, min

I have two files the first with Model, date sold, customer, and serial number (and other data), 2nd has serial number, date of service, service type (there can be more than one date of service for the same serial number) and other data.

I need to select the first date of service for a model for each serial number (but not from subsequent dates). I know I will need to do an inner join on serial number but not sure how to bring back only the first date of service. I expect to use min function on service date but not sure how to structure the query.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want from the second table is the first date of service, then a correlated subquery is good enough:

```
select 
    m.*,
    (
        select min(date_of_service) 
        from services s 
        on s.serial_number = m.serial_number
    ) first_date_of_service
from models m
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `services(serial_number, date_of_service)`.